# What bootstrap classes to use for creating a page with a surrounding background?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter, web

I need to create a website by using Twitter Bootstrap that will be structured like you see in the image. But considering how Bootstrap is build (based on rows and columns), I am not sure what classes to use, so I will be able to have a background around the menu and content area.

Can someone help? Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can add a background to your body. Then, make a `.container` and paste your menu and content inside. 
Add a padding to your `.container`.

I did not try, but I think it can work.

Answer (score 0):

Live example to the @DadaArno answer

UPDATE

```
<div class="content">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: And in this case the "content" div will be divided into 12 columns and I can use the col-md-xx classes inside of this div?